# How to assign a 'get' function to a variable in a model. Typescript

Tags: typescript, model

**code below:**

```
export class User {

constructor(

  public Id: number,
  public Prefix: string,
  public FirstName: string,
  public LastName: string,
  public MiddleInitial: string,
  public FullName: string = function() {
    return FirstName + ' ' + LastName;
  },
){ }
}
```

The fullname variable is throwing an error, any help/other approaches would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state that `FullName` should expect string, but you try to assign function to it.
As you want to assign to FullName value that will be a composition of two constructor params, you have to declare `FullName` as a `User` class field, and assign value to it in constructor body:

```js
class User {
  public FullName: string;
  
  constructor(
    public Id: number,
    public Prefix: string,
    public FirstName: string,
    public LastName: string,
    public MiddleInitial: string,
  ) { 
    this.FullName = FirstName + ' ' + LastName;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want a property getter on your class.

Something like:

```
class User {
    constructor(
        public FirstName: string,
        public LastName: string,
    ){}

    get FullName(): string {
        return this.FirstName + ' ' + this.LastName;
    }
}

console.log(new User('A', 'B').FullName) // 'A B'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2&ssl=12&ssc=50&pln=12&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeBYAUNH1gHsA7CAFyQFdgT8kAKLXR6AB3ICMQBLYaAMU6SkAcmAC2CAFzRSSToQDmAGgZMcrDt2gAZSCRHipMuUpU4AlKgC+WU9HkISfciBD6EtM4bLG0txkgdyJEJoEgALTggAOn5BPTEEaABqaAByNOTQiOidYQSAbltrTGKsAmJ8EAQokHx5WkIEAHc4RDpUgEFUxTSAIVSzGOdXBLNoAHpxtI7ofqA)